# mock patch isn't used by my test function

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, mlflow

Here is a class :

```
import mlflow

class myClass:
   def __init__(self):
      run_id = self.find_most_recent_model()
      logged_model = f'mlruns/0/{run_id}/artifacts/pipeline'
      self.loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)
```

And here is my test class:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
import pytest
class Test:

    @patch('mlflow.MlflowClient.search_runs', Mock(return_value= [Mock(_info=Mock(run_id='mock_run_id'))]))
    @patch('mlflow.pyfunc.load_model', Mock())
    def test_find_most_recent_model(self):
        instance_test = myClass(
        )
```

THe first patch work and is used inside self.find_most_recent_model() but the second patch doesn't work. The result is that mlflow.pyfunc.load_model is not going through the mocked patch and really try to run so i have this error:

```
OSError: No such file or directory: 'mlruns\0\mock_run_id\artifacts\pipeline'
```

Comment: it seems like you are trying to patch the mlflow.pyfunc.load_model method, but the issue might be related to the fact that you are using load_model as an attribute of an instance (self.loaded_model)

Comment: Thanks for answering @jeffreyohene. I tried to replace by test = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model) and i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why but that works :

```
@patch('mlflow.MlflowClient.search_runs', Mock(return_value=[Mock(_info=Mock(run_id='mock_run_id'))]))
@patch('mlflow.pyfunc.load_model', Mock(return_value=Mock()))
def test_find_most_recent_model(self):
    with patch('mlflow.pyfunc.load_model', return_value=Mock()):
        my_instance= MyClass(
        )
```